# Netlify Forms and service worker

Tags: netlify

I'm trying to setup netlify forms on my website. I finger out that this thing doesn't work with my service worker (even when I place just basic SW). Without SW, everything works just fine.

Comment: Can you share the code of your form?

Comment: Can you share the code of your form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thnx to Netlify support I fix my problem. Those guys there are the best (having a free account and so much help from them till today is awesome). Because Service worker hijacks form to request that's why Netlify didn't catch any of my form submissions.

Solution:
You need to disable service worker on the contact page:

```
<script>

  navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(function(registrations) 
    {
        for (let registration of registrations) {
            registration.unregister()
        }
    })
</script>
```

After that service worker will be disabled from now on, if you want to be sure that service worker will work again after submission, just add action to the sucsses page where service worker will be registered again

```
<form name="Netlify Form" method="post" data-netlify="true" action="/send">
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to unregister and re-register your service worker to get netlify forms running with it. A much more simple approach is to bypass the SW cache by always adding a unique string to the url you post your form to.

In my case I am using the browsers fetch method and instead of having it post to just "/" I add a timestamp to the url like so: "/?t=1234652736"

```
const postUrl = '/?t=' + Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

fetch(postUrl, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: ...),
  })
```

You dont have to use fetch it also works with ajax via axios for example.