# Gatsby-plugin-offline - service worker intercepting form POST requests

Tags: gatsby, workbox, gatsby-plugin

I have a page setup with gatsby-plugin-offline.

I finally got everything working offline (documentation is a bit sparse, so this was a bit "trial and error"). But I now have a problem I cannot seem to be able to solve.

My POST requests to Netlify for my contact form is intercepted by the serviceworker. I really do not need any offline-functionality here - I simple "swap" the "send" button in my form for a "network offline" message when users are offline. However, when the page is online the serviceworker still kicks in.

I guess I have to to make some sort of alternative routing for POST requests, but I am not sure how to solve this?

So far this is my setup in gatsby-plugin-offline that works as intended:

```
{
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-offline",
      options: {
        precachePages: [
          `/index.html`,
          `/en/artikler/*`,
          `/en/artikler/*/*`,
          `/en/`,
          `/artikler/*`,
          `/artikler/*/*`,
          `/webudvikling/*`,
          `/en/webudvikling/*`,
          `/grafik/*`,
          `/en/grafik/*`,
          `/kompetencer/*`,
          `/en/kompetencer/*`,
        ],
        workboxConfig: {
          globPatterns: [
            "**/*{.html,.webp,.webmanifest,.woff,.woff2,.ttf,.eot,.css,.svg,.mp3,icons/icon*,.ico, sw.js}",
          ],
        },
      },
    },
```

Documentation for the plugin implies the possibility to append a script to the serviceworker by adding a line under options:

```
appendScript: require.resolve(`./src/custom-sw-code.js`),
```

My idea is then to add something like:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
      /\$?????????/,
      workbox.strategies.networkFirst(),
    )
```

But I am not sure? Can you somehow filter by event.request.method === 'POST'or similar to force any POST requests to Network only?

Answer (score 0):

Ahh sorry. This was already answered elsewhere in this thread:

[Netlify Forms and service worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56539654/netlify-forms-and-service-worker)

In short: Append a unique id to the POST url on every form submit. This way the service worker will not be able to intercept the response as there really is nothing to cache.